# Limit Object properties to the properties of another object

Tags: typescript

I am creating a Object patching utility function and have code as follow

```
class Test{
  a:number;
  b:number;
}

var c:Test={a:0,b:1}

function patchable<T>(obj:T){
  return {
    patch:function<K>(prop:K){
      return patchable({...obj,...prop})},
    value:function():T{return obj}
  }
}

c=patchable(c).patch({notAllow:94}).value()
```

Is it possible with typescript typing to limit the `patch` function to only accept object that contains properties which is only available in `Test` interface, i.e `K` can only contain keys available in `T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Test {
  a: number
  b: number
}

var c: Test = {
  a: 0,
  b: 1
}

function patchable<T>(obj: T) {
  return {
    patch: function <K extends keyof T>(prop: Pick<T, K>) {
      return patchable({ ...obj, ...prop })
    },
    value: function(): T {
      return obj
    }
  }
}

c = patchable(c).patch({ notAllow: 94 }).value() // fails
c = patchable(c).patch({ a: 94 }).value() // compiles
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Partial` works as alternative:

```
class Test {
  a?: number
  b?: number
}

var c: Test = {
  a: 0,
  b: 1
}
function patchable<T>(obj: T) {
  return {
    patch: function (prop: Partial<T>) {
      return patchable({ ...obj, ...prop })
    },
    value: function(): T {
      return obj
    }
  }
}

c = patchable(c).patch({ notAllow: 94 }).value() // fails
c = patchable(c).patch({ a: 94 }).value() // compiles
console.warn(c)
```